# MySQL - getting conditional data

Tags: mysql

This question may be simple but I am confused.
I have a specified ID that I use when getting data from 2 columns.
first column is sender an second one is receiver.
I want to get data from sender when receiver is ID and want to get data from receiver when sender is ID.

```
select sender from table where receiver=ID ;
select receiver from table where sender=ID
```

What I want is how to simplify this query and prevent repeat of same data.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct sender from table where receiver=ID ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach:

```
SELECT DISTINCT IF(t.receiver=ID,t.sender,IF(t.sender=ID,t.receiver,NULL)) AS mycol
  FROM mytable t
 WHERE t.receiver=ID
    OR t.sender=ID
```

Another option is just to combine your current queries with a UNION operator, e.g.

```
SELECT r.sender FROM mytable r WHERE r.receiver=ID 
 UNION
SELECT s.receiver FROM mytable s WHERE s.sender=ID
```

(Note that we use a `UNION` operator rather than a `UNION ALL` operator, so that any duplicate rows will be eliminated from the resultset.)

Comment: This is what I want exactly.Thanks